# ID a scene where a woman shoots a man on a boat without flinching

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

Many years ago I saw a scene from a movie or a tv show and I can't identify it.

There is a woman and two men on a boat. One man is sitting on the bottom of the boat with his legs spread, I don't know if he's injured or is just sitting nonchalantly. He is arguing with the other man about him not killing someone (as in that person being alive will cause problems) and money if I'm not mistaken. Then the "sitting" man points to the woman that's on the boat with them and says something to her. The woman takes out a gun and there's a close-up on her face when she pulls the trigger, there are a few gunshot heard. The close-up switches between showing the woman's face and the standing man. I think it was shot that way to not reveal who was shot by the woman.

That scene stuck with me because I remember my grandad being mad at it because the woman didn't flinch or even blink when the gunshot went off. He said that given the distance and the fact that the gun she was holding was quite big, it's impossible for her face to not react to the flash/sound of the gunshot.
The movie/show was in English, I assume it was action/drama. I can't give a specific time but I think it was made in 80's or 90's (I saw the movie around 2001-2003). The woman was either bald or had really short hair. I don't remember anything distinctive about the men though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm.. you might be looking for [Die Hard with a Vengeance (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112864/), third movie from Die Hard franchise.

The scene you're describing features 3 of the villians of the movie. The "sitting man" as you described it is Targo and he's injured after a fight with John McClane. The other man is Simon Gruber, the main villain of the film. The lady you describe is Katya (blonde, short hair)

Here's a description of the scene:

> Later on the motor boat docked to the freighter, Targo, bloodied and injured, chastised Simon that the containers are filled with scrap metal instead of gold like Simon said. Targo tells Katya that Simon betrayed them by telling them that they would sink the gold, when he really intended on keeping it for himself. Katya pulls her Walther PPK/S but **instead of killing Simon, she shows her loyalty to him by unloading the pistol into Targo**, killing him. This makes him the 14th member of Simon's gang to die, but at Katya's hands.

Katya first point her gun at Simon but then points it at Targo, that's when the gunshot (and the close-ups) happen. There is indeed a flash of light after the gunshot and neither of them blinks.

Comment: Wasn't sure if that's it since you didn't provide any pictures or a video but then I recognized the actor who played the main bad guy ;) Thanks!